# Loading data in Component 2 after selecting component 1 picker View IOS

Tags: ios, loading, uipickerview

There are Three components (projects, tasks and sub tasks )in my pickerview when I select project, I was able to get the project name and respective project ID (Project ID is in label). My requirement is I want to send the project ID to NSURL so that I can load the respective tasks that are assigned to that project ID. Here is my Below Code. 
ViewDidLoad:

```
// Code for Tasks loading
    NSString *nsTaskurllocal = @"http://test.com/";
    NSString *usrid = @"313";
    NSString * productIdString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[self.lblProjects text],usrid];
    NSLog(@"aString : %@", productIdString);
    NSString *aString = [nsTaskurllocal stringByAppendingString:productIdString];


    NSURL *nstaskurl = [NSURL URLWithString:aString];
    NSLog(@"nstaskurl : %@", nstaskurl);

    NSData *nstaskpostData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *nstaskpostLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[nstaskpostData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *nstaskrequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [nstaskrequest setURL:nstaskurl];
    [nstaskrequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [nstaskrequest setValue:nstaskpostLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [nstaskrequest setValue:@"application/projectpicker" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [nstaskrequest setValue:@"application/jsonArray" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [nstaskrequest setHTTPBody:nstaskpostData];


    NSError *nstaskerror = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *nstaskresponse = nil;
    NSData *nstaskurlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:nstaskrequest returningResponse:&nstaskresponse error:&nstaskerror];
    NSURLRequest *nstaskurlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nstaskurl
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                            timeoutInterval:30];


    // Make synchronous request
    nstaskurlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:nstaskurlRequest
                                    returningResponse:&nstaskresponse
                                                error:&nstaskerror];
    if ([nstaskresponse statusCode] >= 200 && [nstaskresponse statusCode] < 300)
    {
        NSString *nstaskresponseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:nstaskurlData
                                                                 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&nstaskerror];

        NSArray *nstaskentries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[nstaskresponseData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                           options:0 error:&nstaskerror];
        if(!nstaskentries)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error : %@", nstaskerror);
        }
        else{

            for (NSDictionary *nstaskentry in nstaskentries) {
                 taskID = [nstaskentries valueForKey:@"ID_TASK"];
                taskNames = [nstaskentries valueForKey:@"TASk_NAME"];

                //NSLog(@"Error : %@", taskNames); //log to see the result in console // by Kiran
            }

            _projectpicker.delegate = self;
            _projectpicker.dataSource = self;
        }

    }       else {

    }
    -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    NSNumber *myProjectArrayString = [projID objectAtIndex:row];
    //NSNumber *myTaskArrayString = [taskID objectAtIndex:row];
    //NSLog(@"%@",myArrayString);
    //NSLog(@"%@",myTaskArrayString);
    lblProjects.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myProjectArrayString];
    //lblProjects.hidden = YES;
    lblTasks.text = [taskNames objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];
    //lblTasks.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myTaskArrayString];
    lblSubTasks.text = [subtaskNames objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]];
}
```

Thanks in Advance 
Kiran Kumar

Comment: So what is the actual problem? Did you try adding content to the picker? Where is that code? Show your picker data source methods.

Comment: Wain Actually I was very new to this IOS. Could you please Elaborate the issue..

Comment: Yes Content of the picker is able to load in Projects, tasks and Sub tasks. But the only prblm I had is I was not able to pass the Project ID (label) to Task for loading the respective data

Comment: When the picker is selected you get `myProjectArrayString`. How do you need to use it?

Comment: And what is stopping you from doing that? Move your URL code to a different method so you can call it multiple times with different values.

Comment: When I keep a Log for NSURL Here is the Result and result for Label is Null :

2014-02-28 17:20:06.903 Demologin[1108:c07] nstaskurl : http://test.com/GetAssignedTasks//313

Comment: Yes, in `viewDidLoad:` the label has just been created (or, depending on how it's loaded, might not even exist yet). Don't load the URL in `viewDidLoad:` if you don't have the info until a selection is made...

Comment: Move your URL code to a different method so you can call it multiple times with different values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48683/discussion-between-user3279508-and-wain)

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate between your *total* data, and your *displayed* data.

So, download all of your data and save it in `projectNames`, `taskNames` and `subtaskNames`. But also have 2 other properties: `currentTaskNames` and `currentSubtaskNames` (you don't need 
`cProjectNames` because the user can always see all project names.

After the download:

```
self.currentTaskNames = taskNames;
self.currentSubtaskNames = subtaskNames;
```

Now, when the user selects a project, filter the tasks and subtasks that are available.

```
switch (component) {
    case 0:
    {
        NSString *project = [projectNames objectAtIndex:row];
        self.currentTaskNames = [taskNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:...];
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        NSString *task = [taskNames objectAtIndex:row];
        self.currentSubtaskNames = [subtaskNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:...];
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    // do something interesting
    break;
}
```

You need to fill in the predicates which filter out the tasks and subtasks that aren't appropriate based on the selected project and task.

---

Also, stop using labels for data storage...

Comment: What Does Line mean self.currentTaskNames = [taskNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:...];

Comment: it filters the `taskNames` based on the selected project. You need to fill in the predicate. based on `taskNames` being the full list of tasks and `currentTaskNames` being used to fill the picker

Comment: Speaking frankly I dont know hoe to use Predicate

Comment: Can U please guide me how to do that, if you wish I can explain you whats my problme again

Comment: I was middle of the sea and cant go further before completing this task. Can U guide me step by step if you are comfortable?

Comment: I was still strucked up here Still I was not able to load the Tasks data accordingly.. :(

Comment: What do you have that actually works? Do you have all of the data downloaded?

Comment: as you said I created Two properties in .h file and trying taskNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:...] With no sucess

Comment: Yes I got Project Data, Task Data and Sub tasks Data in my picker view.

Comment: how do you know which tasks are associated with a project? they contain an id / relationship?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48853/discussion-between-user3279508-and-wain)